# Where can I find details about params of pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.options() method?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I search [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.option.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.option) about how to use this method. But this document didn't had details about what option could I set. Where could I found all supported option key of this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the available options might be listed [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html#data-source-option).